# How can I dequeue all notifications from [NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue]?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I'm trying to test that an asynchronous NSNotifcation is sent, and I'd like to make sure all notifications have been dequeued before I check that the notification was received.

It appears that I can't use `NSNotificationQueue`'s only dequeue method,

```
- (void)dequeueNotificationsMatching:(NSNotification *)notification coalesceMask:(NSUInteger)coalesceMask
```

because my test doesn't know the notification, so it can't match against it.

Comment: Have you tried passing `nil` as the notification and seeing if it matches everything? That pattern is common with the other Notification-based objects.

Answer (score 1):

The notification was set with the `NSPostingStyle`, `NSPostWhenIdle`, so the solution was to include this line before verifying the mock.

```
  [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.1]];
```